# Change a substring in the name of some files

Tags: r

How can I change a substring in the name of all the files in a folder?

Example, list of files in the folder (input):

```
c("Comment1 03_2020.docx", "Comment2 03_2020.docx", "Comment4 03_2020.docx")
```

substring to change: from "03_2020" to "04_2023"

Desired output:

```
c("Comment1 04_2023.docx", "Comment2 04_2023.docx", "Comment4 04_2023.docx")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a vector of file names.

```
files <- list.files("/file_dir", pattern = "\\b03_2020", full.names = TRUE)
```

Rename the files.

```
file.rename(files, stringr::str_replace(files, "\\b03_2020", "04_2023"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `gsub()`. The following would achieve what you're looking for:

```
# list the files in a directory (if you want the absolute path names, use full.names = T
files <- list.files("path/to/dir")

# Replace string with gsub
files_new <- gsub("03_2020", "04_2023", files)

# Then you can rename with rename() or whatever you had in mind
```